# Local storage browser for Google Cloud Storage and dev_appserver.py

Tags: google-cloud-storage

Does anyone know if there is a version of the Google Cloud Storage storage browser (console.developers.google.com/project/apps~{application name}/storage) to use during development?

There doesn't seem to be any such tool as part of the admin server that is started at localhost:8000 when dev_appserver.py is launched.

If no such tool exists, how do others develop against the local Google Cloud Storage service during development? Do they end up writing their own tools to upload files, delete files, and view the current contents of the local Google Cloud Storage running on top of the local filesystem?

Answer (score 2):

Cloud Storage Viewer is not available for local development server. GCS client library can be used to run local tests.

Answer (score 2):

If you visit the admin server at localhost:8000 you can see the files inside of the blobstore viewer. You can tell they are GCS files because their keys will start with `encoded_gs_file:` but you cannot see the filenames.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the files I wrote to google cloud storage when running locally at:

```
     localhost:port/_ah/gcs/bucket_name/file_suffix
```

Where port is by default 8080, and the file was written to: /bucket_name/file_suffix

It's still not ideal for testing, but better than nothing!