# Manage local cloud storage instance using gsutil

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I have a GAE based application that pulls a file from cloud storage and then does some processing on that file. To run the application in the remote appengine environment, I first upload a file to cloud storage using the browser console, and then make requests to the application, which pulls the file I uploaded from cloud storage. I'd like to be able to do development locally, however there is not a sweet browser console for the local implementation of gcs, as discussed here: [Local storage browser for Google Cloud Storage and dev_appserver.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25110110/local-storage-browser-for-google-cloud-storage-and-dev-appserver-py).

I'm wondering if it's possible to use gsutil. It seems the local gcs implementation is accessible through a localhost endpoint, mentioned here: [Google Cloud Storage on Appengine Dev Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20158135/google-cloud-storage-on-appengine-dev-server).

Right now, what I want to do is just load a file into my local gcs instance. I could do this my writing a little utility, but it seems much better to use gsutil if I can get that to connect to my local instance.

Thank you,

Ben

Comment: Can you specify what you want to develop : a CLI based on gsutil or a web app on GAE?

Comment: Hi Greg, I just edited the question, hopefully that makes it more clear. I'm developing a web app on GAE.

Comment: Write a simple upload handler in your webapp is probably the quickest solution.

Comment: OK, good to know. Thank you!